# Jackson and Iterable: how to deserialize

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class `Box` which has a field `elements` which is of type `Elements` that implements `Iterable` (see the code below).  The latter contains a `List` which is also called `elements`

If I set the field `elements` of `Elements` to be `private`, then the serialization would treat it as an array rather than a POJO

*Serialization done by Version A*

```
{
  "elements" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

However, I could not deserialize this string.  The error was:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `ser_deser_test.Elements` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "elements" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}"; line: 2, column: 16] (through reference chain:
```

If I, instead, set `elements` to be `public`, then `elements` of `Box` would be treated as a POJO, and I had this funny two levels of `elements` in it.  The deserialization worked in this case, however.

*Serialization by Version B*

```
{
  "elements" : {
    "elements" : [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I get deserializatio to work for Version A?

**Code**

*Box.java*

```
package ser_deser_test;

public class Box {
    public Box() {
        super();
    }

    public Elements elements;

    public Box(Elements elements) {
        super();
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

*Elements.java*

```
package ser_deser_test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public class Elements implements Iterable<String> {
    // private List<String> elements; // Version A
    // public List<String> elements;  // Version B

    public Elements() {
        super();
    }

    public Elements(List<String> elements) {
        super();
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return elements.iterator();
    }

}
```

*TestSerDeser.java*

```
package ser_deser_test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class TestSerDeser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elements elements = new Elements(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
        Box      box = new Box(elements);

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        om.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            // Serialize
            String s = om.writeValueAsString(box);

            // Deserialize
            Box box2 = om.readValue(s, Box.class);

            boolean dummy = false;

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with:

```
package ser_deser_test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public class Elements implements Iterable<String> {
    // private List<String> elements; // Version A
    public List<String> elements;  // Version B

    public Elements() {
        super();
    }

    public Elements(List<String> elements) {
        super();
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return elements.iterator();
    }

}
```

and fails with `Version A` decommented because, by default, Jackson  doesn't have acces to private fields. To make it work with `Version A` modify `TestSerDeser` class like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

in order to allow Jackson access the private field `List<String> elements` or, even better, add a public getter for this field.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using simple property of `List<String>`?

```
public class Elements {

   public List<String> elements;
```

Or as @EugenCovaci comment if you don't need specific Object

```
 public class Box {
   public List<String> elements; //directly into Box class
```

For keeping `private List<String> elements;` just add getter to be used as property:

```
public List<String> getElements() {
   return elements;
}
```

Also you can add [@JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526874/jsonproperty-annotation-on-field-as-well-as-getter-setter)

```
  @JsonProperty
  private List<String> elements;
```

Comment: Or put `List<String> elements;` directly into `Box` class.

Comment: Thanks (to both you and @Engen Covaci) -- Assuming that we need to keep the structure of Version A, is there a way to deserialize properly?

Comment: @leeyuiwah see my updated, add getter `public List<String> getElements() {
       return elements;
    }`

Comment: @leeyuiwah Just add `om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);` See my answer. A public getter is even better.