# What is the difference between @JsonProperty when set on variable, getter and setter?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I understand that JsonProperty is used to map the variable to JSON key if the key is different from the variable.

Below is my sample POJO:-

```
 public class JsonProperty {
        @JsonProperty("studentId")  //---------------variable
        private String id;
        
        @JsonProperty("studentId")  //---------------getter
        public String getIdValue() {
            return id;
        }
        
        @JsonProperty("studentId")  //---------------setter
        public void setIdValue(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
}
```

JSON String: {"studentId" : "so1"}

Let's say that we are saving in DB using some JDBC code. I observed the below changes but could not accurately understand the behavior.

1. If @JsonProperty("studentId") is not used on a variable, getter and setter.
   observation: Noting is stored on DB.
2. If @JsonProperty("studentId") is used on variable alone.
   Observation:  {"idValue" : "so1"} is stored in DB.
3. If  @JsonProperty("studentId") is used on setter or getter.
   Observation: {"studentId" : "so1"} is stored in DB.

So, Could you explain what is the actual behavior that happens when we use JsonProperty on variable, getter and setter???

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526874/jsonproperty-annotation-on-field-as-well-as-getter-setter. There is an order of precedence between the different annotations

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest explanation is:
@JsonProperty(name), tells Jackson ObjectMapper to map the JSON property name to the annotated Java field's name.